# Load data from Document file to CKEDITOR - PHP

Tags: php, ckeditor

I'm newbie to PHP, i need to display the uploaded document file content into CKEEDITOR widget.

Can anyone provide me idea to do this or any possibility is there ?

Comment: What kind of document file do you have MS word?

Comment: @SaadSuri document with tables and images